# Mesh Overlay from Scene view in Game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is a bit of a difficult question to search because "mesh" actually means something in Unity, but anyway... I was wondering if there is a way to be able to incorporate the blue 'mesh' overlay effect on top of an object selected in the scene view, except in game. It doesn't look readily available, but I feel like if it's there in the scene view there should be some way to activate it in the game. I want to use it for a 'highlight' or hover-over feature for some objects.

I'm basically referring to what surrounds the capsule in this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lUR2.png

Answer (score 1):

You want something called a `wireframe shader` or `wireframe renderer`. There are some paid versions in the asset store as well as a couple of scripts that should help you achieve this look.

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/wireframe-shader-the-amazing-wireframe-shader.251143/
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/144693/wireframe-rendering.html
http://www.starscenesoftware.com/vectrosity.html